Best practices for the deployment of upgrades from 9.4 to 10.3
I am in the process of upgrading a Drupal site from Drupal 9.4 to Drupal 10.3. In my local I can achieve this sequentially like follows

Upgrade to 9.5 - Run composer install, config import, clear caches, db updates, clear caches.
Disable deprecated stuff - Run composer install, config import, clear caches, db updates, clear caches
Upgrade to 10.3 - Run composer install, config import, clear caches, db updates, clear caches

I use git tags to switch to the relevant commits to perform these operations.
The thing is I would like to do this with a single branch at one go possibly using custom scripts. What are the best practices available for this.

Best practice is incremental updates and deployments. One chunk at a time.

Is this question asking to clarify or to re-document the official documentation? https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10 It doesn't say that it is.

The best practice is to do one core upgrade at a time, not try to do multiple core upgrades in an automated sequence.
You could write a script to do this, but I imagine the error handling for all the things that could go wrong would be a nightmare.  If it's a single site, I think it would be much easier to do one upgrade, check the logs and run any tests you have to make sure everything is ok, and then run the next upgrade.
As for all the tasks like config import, clear caches, etc., just use drush; a quick and easy way is to write a php script and execute it with the php:script command.

This is the correct answer. Thanks
